# Trouble setting API key in POST request

Tags: php, curl, http-post

trying to make an API request via curl. The API docs say I must make a POST request as follows:

```
POST url
Headers: 
    Content-Type: “application/json”
Body:
{
    Context: {
        ServiceAccountContext: "[Authorization Token]"
    },
    Request:{
            Citations:[
            {
                Volume: int,
                Reporter: str,
                Page: int
            }
            ]   
    }
}
```

Here is my curl request:

```
$postFields = array(
            'Volume' => int, 
            'Reporter' => str, 
            'Page' => int,
            'ServiceAccountContext' => $API_KEY
);   

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);       
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:application/json"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($postFields));        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);         

$output=curl_exec($ch);
```

But the API is not recognizing that I have submitted the API_KEY through a POST Field. The error I am getting back is to create a SecurityContext object, which I assume is something to do with the part of the POST body talking about Context and ServiceAccountContext.

I have looked in the cURL documentation and have not seen how I can set this. Any suggestions? Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use CURL options improperly. According to [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), when you set `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option to an `array`, CURL forces `Content-Type` header to `multipart/form-data`. i.e. the line where you set `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option is ignored.

You have to convert `$postFields` to JSON string by `json_encode` function before passing it to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option:

```
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:application/json"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);       
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postFields));         
...
```

Comment: Thanks hindmost, I had just begun to do exactly what you said (use json_encode) before reading your answer. The API key is now being recognized, now I am just tinkering with the Request part to make that work. Thanks for confirming to me I am on the right track.

Comment: @Cbomb You could choose this answer as "accepted" if it solve your problem